# How do I create a tree structure with an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

My problem is that I would like to create a tree structure in JSON format from flat data from a mySQL query.

the array that I have coming from mySQL query is in the format: `{"Level":"Higher","Course":"Administration and IT","Grade":"A"`}, ...etc

Is there a way to order this into a tree format using JavaScript? Or do I need to include the hierarchical structure within the database?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: You can do it in either Javascript or PHP, but not in MySQL at it returns flat result sets.

Comment: Yes it can be done with php or js.. But adding what's actual array "really" look like..`print_r($your_array)` and what's your desired json object to your question is suggested..